# jquery is appending "#!/undefined" to the url , back functionality is not working

Tags: jquery, url

I am using jquery 1.7.1.js

If i run my project at the end of url, #!/undefined is appending like

`http://localhost:6060/saraswathi_achala_web/faqs.action#!/undefined`

I don't know why?

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some jQuery plugin or other script loaded which is attempting to preserve state with a "[hashbang](https://www.google.com/search?q=hashbang%20url)".  You'll need to figure out what plugin is doing it and either disable it or figure out how to work with it correctly.  We can't really tell you what script is doing it; try searching your scripts for `location.hash`.

Comment: Thanq MightyE,
there are 9 scripts in my template, in every script there is "location.hash" at some places.  
So , what I need to do now?